# Flutter: Retrieving top-level state from child returns null

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to obtain the top-level state of my app using a .of()-method, similar to the Scaffold.of() function. This is the (stripped down) code:

```
class IApp extends StatefulWidget {    
  @override
  IAppState createState() => new IAppState();

  static IAppState of(BuildContext context) =>
    context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<IAppState>());
}
```

The app is started using runApp(new IApp)

This Widget creates a HomePage:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      // ommitted: some localization and theming details
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
```

Then, I try to access the State from the HomePage (a StatefulWidget itself):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      // ommited: some Scaffold properties such as AppBar
      // runtimeType not actual goal, but just for demonstration purposes
      body: new Text(IApp.of(context).runtimeType.toString()),
    );
  }
```

The strange this is, the code works when I place the code for HomePage **in the same file** as the IApp, but just as an extra class. However, when I place HomePage **in a separate file** (main.dart and homepage.dart importing each other), the return value of IApp.of(context) is null.

What causes this? And how can I fix it?

Comment: dumb question, it could be irrelevant but, when importing your files, are you using relative path ("./homepage.dart") or absolute path ("package:my_package/homepage.dart") ?

Comment: I am using absolute pathing, so like package:my_package/etc/file.dart

Comment: I had a similar bug a long time ago, I am not sure but using relative path solved it, or it was something else ^^

Comment: This did indeed fix it, thanks a lot! I'm still awaiting a "proper" reply (as to what causes this, and why relative imports fix it), so I'm not marking the question as answered yet. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**TDLR**: imports file only using

```
import 'package:myApp/path/myFile.dart';
```

Never with

```
import './myFile.dart';
```

---

This is due to how dart resolves imports.

You may have a single source file, but during builds, there is some kind of duplicates.

Let's say you're working on 'myApp'. To import a file, you could do both :

- `import 'relativePath/myFile.dart'`
- `import 'package:myApp/path2/myFile.dart'`

You'd think that they point to the same file right?
But no. One of them will point to the original source. While the other one will point to a temporary file used for the build.

The problem comes when you start to mix both solutions. Because for the compiler, these two files are **different**. Which means that `IApp` imported from `package:myApp/IApp` is not equal to the same `IApp` imported from `relativePath/myApp/IApp`

In your case, you inserted in your widget tree an `IApp` from `pakage:path` but your `IApp.of(context)` use `IAppState` resolved locally.
They both have a different runtimeType. Therefore `const TypeMatcher<IAppState>()` won't match. And your function will return null.

---

There's an extremely easy way to test this behavior. 
Create a `test.dart` file containing only

```
class Test {
}
```

then in your `main.dart` add the following imports :

```
import 'package:myApp/test.dart' as Absolute;
import './test.dart' as Relative;
```

You can finally test this by doing :

```
new Relative.Test().runtimeType == new Absolute.Test().runtimeType
```

Spoiler: the result is false

Comment: I used absolute import but this issue still happens. Any other clue?

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure this is not the case. Dart is capable of canonicalizing relative and absolute paths. There was a Flutter related issue fixed a few weeks ago that broke this canonicalization because the entry-point file is in `lib/` instead of `bin/` how it was originally designed in Dart. I have seen it mentioned that there can still be cases on Windows when uppercase letters are used in file names that break this, but I don't use Windows hand haven's experienced that.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm certain this was true at some point. But this may have been fixed in the meantime, I haven't checked it yet

Comment: While it was true it was only when relative imports were used `lib/main.dart`. If this file contained only package imports, then you could mix relative and package imports everywhere else.

Answer (score 4):

Now you can use the relative path.

You can verify this, as Remy suggested two years ago:

```
Relative.Test().runtimeType == Absolute.Test().runtimeType
```

Spoiler: the result is true