# Localize a widget in Flutter

Tags: localization, dart, flutter

I'm currently test driving and I have already built a localized "Hello world" following the [tutorial](https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/). However, when I tried to move my widget to a different file, I got a red screen of death with the error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building ToDoItem(dirty):
The method 'helloWorld' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: helloWorld()
```

My To Do item class looks like this

**todo_item.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/localization.dart';

class ToDoItem extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text(ToDoLocalizations.of(context).helloWorld());
  }
}
```

Of course the problem is that my Localization class has not been initialized, however I don't know how to initialize it since the `Text` widget does not have a `LocalizationDelegates` parameter.

I'm aware that this could be fixed by injecting the String directly into my widget's constructor, but for the sake of it I want to know how to localize widgets.

**EDIT:** Here is my localization class

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:to_do_app/l10n/messages_all.dart';

class ToDoLocalizations {
  ToDoLocalizations(Locale locale) : _localeName = locale.toString();

  final String _localeName;

  static Future<ToDoLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    return initializeMessages(locale.toString()).then((Object _) {
      return new ToDoLocalizations(locale);
    });
  }

  static ToDoLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<ToDoLocalizations>(context, ToDoLocalizations);
  }

  String helloWorld() {
    return Intl.message(
        'Hello, World!',
        name: 'helloWorld',
        desc: 'A friendly salutation',
        locale: _localeName
    );
  }
}

class ToDoLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<ToDoLocalizations> {


  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    return ['en', 'nb'].contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(LocalizationsDelegate<ToDoLocalizations> old) {
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Future<ToDoLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    return ToDoLocalizations.load(locale);
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62991563/flutter-nosuchmethoderro-the-method-tr-was-called-on-null-receiver-null/65068136#65068136 maybe it is relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closely following the aforementioned tutorial and the code outlined on this example [repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/stocks) without success, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121411/flutter-retrieving-top-level-state-from-child-returns-null) pointed me in the right direction. All of my code was sound and the only missing part was to write import statements using relative paths instead of absolute paths and then the error disappeared.

Comment: The relative path solution does not work for me, do you have a complete sample code solution ?

Comment: I used this [repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/stocks) as a guideline for my implementation.

Comment: For sample code, refer to this blog: https://blog.geekyants.com/flutter-in-app-localization-438289682f0c

Answer (score 0):

I had added the MaterialApp widget in main.dart, further again in some of files i added MaterialApp by accident. So, adding the second MaterialApp widget overrode what I had previously defined.