# Why Flutter GlobalKey's currentState is NULL when accessed from other file

Tags: dart, key, state, flutter

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyStatefulApp(key: App.appStateKey));
}

/// Part [A]. No difference when appStateKey is defined as variable.
class App {
  static final GlobalKey<MyAppState> appStateKey = new GlobalKey<MyAppState>();
}

/// Part [B] 
class MyStatefulApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulApp({Key key}) :super(key: key);

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyStatefulApp> {

  int _counter = 0;

  add() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "App",
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: _counter % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

/// Part [C] 
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Main"),      ),
      body: new FlutterLogo(),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          App.appStateKey.currentState.add(); // (X)
        },
        tooltip: "Trigger color change",
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the code above, when the FAB is clicked, `MaterialApp` should rebuild, and the primary color will switch between blue and red.

In fact, the code worked, until I attempted to split the portions of the code to different files. `App.appStateKey.currentState` on line (X) will be become `null` when:

- Part A (The `App` class, or the variable) is moved to another file;
- Part C (`MyHomePage` and `_MyHomePageState`) is moved to another file;
- Part A and C are moved to another file

So it looks like the `GlobalKey.currentState` only work when everything involving this GlobalKey is in the same file.

The doc only states that `currentState` will be null when `(1) there is no widget in the tree that matches this global key, (2) that widget is not a StatefulWidget, or the associated State object is not a subtype of T.` It doesn't state that everything has to be in the same file.

Breaking classes into files may not be "the Dart way", but I assume it should work anyhow (they're all public). So this puzzles me, and I suspect if I have stumbled upon certain Flutter feature that I am not aware of. Thanks.

Comment: What are the involved files and how are they imported?

Comment: For instance, when I move the `App` class to another file called `types.dart` which is imported in `main.dart` with the following statement:

    `import 'package:testapp/types.dart';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is due to how dart import works.

In dart, there is two way to import sources :

- import './relative/path.dart'
- import 'myApp/absolute/path.dart'

The thing is, they are not compatible with each others. Both these imports will have a different `runtimeType`.

*But how is that a problem ? I never used relative import*

That's a problem, because in some situations you implicitly use "relative imports" : When using a class A defined in `foo.dart` *inside* `foo.dart`.

*So, how do I solve the problem ?*

There are multiple solutions :

- Have everything related to your class `App` should be inside the same file. (That's the recommended thing in dart)
- Extract `App` into it's own file. And import it everywhere using absolute imports.
- Don't use `GlobalKey` to begin with. As your use case is definitely in the scope of `InheritedWidget`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this direction. But my actual problem is due to the use of the "package:" directive to import local package files (or to be exact, the Flutter plugin in Android Studio did this for me). I have to use relative import, so that Dart won't see it as another package. I got the answer after asking in the Flutter discussion forum. And yes, using GlobalKey isn't a good idea for this particular case. I ended up passing a method callback to the child widget.

Comment: That's exactly what I said here :)

Comment: I made a better explanation of this "package" problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121411/flutter-retrieving-top-level-state-from-child-returns-null/47142052#47142052)

Comment: And discussed a lot about it on flutter gittter