# Flutter - Redirect after getting firebase notification

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a fcm_service class (this service is not a widget) with my firebase configure method :

```
firebaseMessaging.configure(onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
  print("onLaunch called");
}, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
  print("onResume called");
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}, onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
  print("onMessage called : " + msg.toString());
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
});
```

I want to be redirected on my main page in "onResume" but nothing happens. When I press on the notification, onResume is called (the print works).

What I've been trying :

- Calling my page like : new MainPage();
- Setting the context of my parent widget in my fcm_service class and use the Navigator like in the code above.

Is it even possible to be redirected through this class which is not a widget ?

EDIT :

Here is my main class :

```
class PreesmApp extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _PreesmAppState createState() => _PreesmAppState();
}

class _PreesmAppState extends State<PreesmApp>{
  AuthenticationBloc _authenticationBloc;
  final FCMService fcmService = Injector.getInjector().get<FCMService>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _authenticationBloc = AuthenticationBloc();
    _authenticationBloc.dispatch(AppStarted());
    super.initState();
    fcmService.setContext(context);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _authenticationBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
        bloc: _authenticationBloc,
        child: MaterialApp(
          supportedLocales: [
            const Locale('en', 'EN'),
        const Locale('fr', 'BE')
      ],
      localizationsDelegates: [
        const DemoLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      localeResolutionCallback:
          (Locale locale, Iterable<Locale> supportedLocales) {
        for (Locale supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
          if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode ||
              supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
            return supportedLocale;
          }
        }

        return supportedLocales.first;
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState>(
        bloc: _authenticationBloc,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AuthenticationState state) {
          if (state is AuthenticationUninitialized) {
            return SplashScreen();
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
            return DashboardPage();
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
            return AuthenticationPage();
          }
          if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
            return LoadingIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
      routes: {
        '/login': (context) =>  AuthenticationPage(),
        '/dashboard': (context) =>  DashboardPage(),
        'menu': (context) =>  MenuPage(),
        '/kanbanBoard': (context) =>  KanbanBoardPage(),
        '/listBoard': (context) =>  ListBoardPage(),
        '/ganttBoard': (context) =>  GanttBoardPage(),
        '/preesm': (context) =>  PreesmApp(),
      },
      theme: ThemeSwitcher.of(context).themeData,
    ));
  }
}
```

And this is my context setter in fcm_service

```
  setContext(BuildContext c) {
    this.context = c;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Is it even possible to be redirected through this class which is not a widget ?
```

As long as you have `BuildContext` as **context**, I'd say yes. You can push new widgets like this

```
Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
```

Have you tried to pass `BuildContext` along to your, let's say `FirebaseMessaging` class, when instantiating it? So that you can push new Widgets?

[Here the Navigation cookbook ref](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

Not sure if it helps you tho.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The way to use the Navigator is not the problem, I tried your code but nothing changes. I think i tried all the Navigator possibilities btw.
My FirebaseMessaging class is a dependency injection instantiated directly on launch and I set the context of my parent widget directly in his initState function

Comment: Maybe I set the bad context. I have many pages but they are all children of my main page, and I use the context of this main page

Comment: I see what you mean. Can I see your **main()**? Another option would be go with a **heavier** strategy by using **GlobalKeys** https://stackoverflow.com/a/50592224/3353024

Comment: I have understood my problem by looking to your link with gloabal keys! I was setting my context in the initState() of my main app but I think my context was not build (not sure). So, i copy/paste my setContext everywhere in my main app to try and it is working. Thank you for your help !