# Flutter navigatorkey + GlobalKey: "method 'pushedName' was called on null"

Tags: flutter, navigator

I've found the ["GlobalKey NavigatorState" solution for middleware here](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/issues/5) but was unable to overcome the error "The method 'pushedNamed' was called on null".  I then found this [alternative solution to fix the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303441/flutter-redux-navigator-globalkey-currentstate-returns-null%20%22%22) using a separate class and static variable, but it yielded the same error.  **All I really need is a very basic example** of the setup and how to call the "pushedNamed" function somewhere else.

**Current code**

initialize GlobalKey in separate folder:

```
class NavKey{
  static final navKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}
```

main.dart:

```
import 'package:eumag/assets/tools/route_navigation_constants.dart';

    ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreProvider<AppState>(
      store: store,
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark(),
        navigatorKey: NavKey.navKey,
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          ROUTE_LOGIN_PAGE: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage(store),
          ROUTE_MAIN_PAGE: (BuildContext context) => MainPage(store),
        },
        home: StoreBuilder<AppState>(
          builder: (BuildContext context, Store<AppState> store) =>
              LoginPage(store),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

middleware.dart:

```
import 'package:eumag/assets/tools/route_navigation_constants.dart';

void appStateMiddleware (Store<AppState> store, action, NextDispatcher next) async{

  final navigatorKey = NavKey.navKey;

  if (action is UpdateRoomStatus){
    navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(ROUTE_MAIN_PAGE);
    store.dispatch(createSocketConnection);
  }
  next(action);
}
```

Comment: You'll get this error if an `UpdateRoomStatus` action is dispatched before your app renders for the first time. You have to wait until the key is attached to the navigator before you can use it.

Comment: i had the same error, but my issue was that i used "key" instead of "navigatorKey" in my MaterialApp

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue, the last line in the docs seems to give a hint for the fix.

[navigatorKey property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/navigatorKey.html)

You apparently can't use `routes` with a `navigatorKey` and must use `onGenerateRoute`.

Comment: after 3 hours, found your answer and solution, thanks

Comment: @ZinoHofmann you dont give any code examples and give a poor explanation. I wouldnt of checked it either

Comment: ah....we use routes / goRouter....hm, what's the way to go to a route in other parts of an app?  Specifically from main (I am using a listener for deep links to then determine routes)

Comment: @satchel did you find anything? I am using gorouter and i want to use navigation in my dio interceptor

Comment: @HadiKhan no I ended up not using it.