# Change VS Code to auto-import files in flutter relatively

Tags: flutter, dart, import

So, here is the problem:

Whenever I am coding with `Flutter and Dart`, and I use a feature from another file, when I press `Tab`, VS Code will auto-import the file for me.

The thing is, VS Code will use the package import syntax, like `import 'package:<project_name>/<file_path>';`. But I prefer relative import syntax.

So, is there a setting I can change in VS Code for Dart to configure it to use relative imports by default?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter imports : relative path or package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693195/flutter-imports-relative-path-or-package)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't necessary to download an extension.
As explained [here](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/prefer_relative_imports), simply add this to the `analysis_options.yaml` file:

```yaml
linter:
  rules:
    - prefer_relative_imports
```

Answer (score 9):

While importing, you can find both option by tapping on yellow bulb or pressing `ctrl+.`

[image]

Another handy thing, using [dart-import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=luanpotter.dart-import) extension on Vs-code.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Is there a way to have the relative path have the `./` at the beginning?

Comment: i could not find that way,

Comment: ok thanks @Yeasin Sheikh!

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I am using [dart-import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=luanpotter.dart-import) extension. There is an extension setting you can turn on to modify imports on save. So, you can have a consistent import structure without needing to choose every single time.

[image: dart import fix on save]

There is a recommendation in [effective dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-relative-import-paths) guideline for relative path import usage.

Comment: Note: After installing the extension, I had to restart VS Code before the "Fix On Save" option appeared.