# How can I change the pathing for autoimports with Flutter and VSCode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Whatever I auto-import (CTRL+.) gets imported using the "package:" syntax. That's fine when it's a package, but it's bothersome when I'm trying to import local files, and my understanding is that it's not best practice either; local files should be imported with a standard filepath.

For example, if I've got a utility I've written that I want to import into main.dart, the import should look like:

`import 'utilities/my_utility.dart';`

Instead, it's coming out as:

`import 'package:my_app/utilities/my_utility.dart';`

Comment: Already answered here [Flutter imports: relative path or package?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66188522/5882307)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the

> dart-import

extension from the extensions section in vs code. You can add the page you want to import by clicking the yellow light bulb in any path you want.

Output: [image]